# How I can manage optional values in Firebase Firestore and avoid empty fields in database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my context, there is the possibility of optional values.

For example, in this database, the field `iVisperas` can be empty in multiple cases. I think is a bad practice to keep empty fields (?).

[image]

Into my code, I map the snapshot to one class.

I don't want to keep the field `iVisperas` as an empty field in Firestore but I don't know how to determine from the model class if this field exists or not.

How I can achieve this. This is my model class from the document. Actually, at `getTituloVisperas` method I check if field `iVisperas` is empty. If I want to create `iVisperas` field only when it contains data, how I can manage that into the model class?

```
public class MetaLiturgia {
    private String fecha;
    private int tiempo;
    private String semana;
    private String mensaje;
    private String salterio;
    private int color;
    private String meta;
    private String titulo;
    private String iVisperas;

    private int weekDay;

    public MetaLiturgia() {
    }

    public String getTituloVisperas() {
        if (iVisperas.equals("")){
            return titulo;
        }else{
            return iVisperas;
        }

    }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, in this database the field iVisperas can be empty in multiple cases.

Seeing that all the fields in your `MetaLiturgia` class are set to private, I assume that you are using a constructor and public getters. If you want that your `iVisperas` property not to hold any value then simply do **not** instantiate it in the constructor or create another constructor without it.

> If I want to create `iVisperas` field only when it contains data, how I can manage that into the model class?

In that case, you should use a `Map` and [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) that document only when the value for your `iVisperas` property is available.

> I think is a bad practice to keep empty fields (?).

There is no benefit in keeping empty fields as long as are not needed. Remember, every property count in that [1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) maximum size for a document.

According to Suhas Ch's answer, please also note that a property of type String which is empty (`""`) and a property which holds `null`, occupy the same amount of space in a document.

**Edit:**

Another possible solution is to assign a default value, in this case, `0`, right inside the model (MetaLiturgia) class.

Comment: Ok. As you says, i'm usging public setters and getters in the class. And I using a Map for fill the class: `JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(calSnapshot.get("meta"));
                mLiturgia = new Liturgia();
                mLiturgia.setMetaLiturgia(gson.fromJson(jsonElement, MetaLiturgia.class));`

Comment: No, you should use a `Map` to update the value of `iVisperas` property in the document, only when the data is available. If you don't have any data, don't store an empty (`""`) String, not even a `null`. So add that property only when you have some data to store in.

Comment: OK. But how i determine from the class (model) when there is data for `iVisperas` property. This is my issue at this moment. How I can achieve this in the class?

Comment: When you are mapping a document to an object of your `MetaLiturgia` class, simply check the `iVisperas` field for nullity. If that field is `==` to `null` it means that it doesn't exist, otherwise it has some value. But you may simply want to use `toObject(MetaLiturgia.class)` method rather than other methods.

Comment: For my context i solved the issue creating the field with a default value (`0`) in the model and then i check if after to map the snapshoot to the class the value of this field is `0` or not. I use the content of  `meta` for multiple activities in my app and in some cases i need to change date based on the value of `iVisperas`. I think i found my way thanks to your comments and suggestions.

Comment: Can you add one mention to default value in the answer for accept it. I solved the issue managing one default value in the model class. Thanks.

Comment: This is what makes Firebase frustrating to use. It only supports a small subset of types. Inter-op with other JVM languages (e.g. Scala) is difficult due to this impedance mismatch.

Comment: @M.K. Do you have a concrete situation? If yes, add a question here, on Stackoverflow so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @AlexMamo the issues I have with the Java client are not really suited to discuss via SO Q/A format. Is your team on Discord by any chance? I would like to discuss how I can make a Scala client for Firebase. I did take a look under the hood of the Java client and one of the biggest issues is that JSON serialisation library that is used and the constraints around that.

Comment: @M.K. Unfortunately, we are not on Discord. But if there are some issues regarding the JSON serialization, you can also contact the Firebase team for that.

Answer (score 0):

While creating field, set the type for `iVisperas` as `null`
[image]

and in the model class

```
public class MetaLiturgia {
    private String fecha;
    private int tiempo;
    private String semana;
    private String mensaje;
    private String salterio;
    private int color;
    private String meta;
    private String titulo;
    private String iVisperas;

    private int weekDay;

    public MetaLiturgia() {
    }

    public String getTituloVisperas() {
        if (iVisperas.equals(null)){
            return titulo;
        }else{
            return iVisperas;
        }

    }
//...
}
```

Comment: Is not a bad pratice to maintain `null` or empty values in Firebase?

Comment: empty values? - Maybe.
null? - I think no

Answer (score 0):

When do you know if the field is empty?
You could delete attribute from your model class and create another class which inherits fro your model class.
There you can add the value. When it comes to saving the object, you wont write the field if its not used. 
But I dont know if this is worth the effort, since you will have to create a newObject of the subclass once your attribute is used.